# Why does mod 2^n use CLTD instruction for signed numbers

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, x86, compiler-optimization

So I know when you do `x mod 2^n` for unsigned operations, the compiler will simply convert that operation into `x & (2^n - 1)`.

But when I look at the compiler implementation using signed numbers, e.g.

```
int signed_rem8(int x) { return x %8; }
```

I get something like this (https://godbolt.org/z/xY3Ef6WEc):

```
 movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
 cltd
 shrl    $29, %edx
 addl    %edx, %eax
 andl    $7, %eax
 subl    %edx, %eax
```

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: You might get machine code that makes more sense if you turn the optimizer on.

Comment: I see that the machine code does change with optimizations, but the question still remains, what is the logic behind using CLTD?

Comment: Cltd copies the sign bit of eax to all bits of edx.  This results in edx=0 if eax is nonnegative and edx=-1 if eax is negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the behaviour of the modulo operator with negative numbers.

The behaviour of this operator is such that `a/b` is rounded towards zero and `a%b` returns a number such that `(a/b)*a + a%b` is equal to `a` (cf. ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.5 ¶6).  As “rounding towards zero” means to round up for negative results and down for positive results, this effectively means that the remainder takes the sign of the numerator.

To implement this behaviour correctly, the compiler makes use of the `cltd` instruction (sign-extending `eax` into `edx:eax`) as follows:

```
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # load numerator x
cltd                    # edx = x >= 0 ? 0 : -1
shrl    $29, %edx       # edx = x >= 0 ? 0 :  7
addl    %edx, %eax      # eax = x >= 0 ? x : x + 7
andl    $7, %eax        # eax = x >= 0 ? x&7 : x-1 & 7
subl    %edx, %eax      # eax = x >= 0 ? x&7 : (x-1 & 7) - 7
```

So in case of a positive number, we get a positive remainder in the range 0 to 7 while in case of a negative number we get a negative remainder in the range −7 to 0.

In both cases, the remainder is numerically correct as the remainder is supposed to be a representant of the residue class *x* mod 8, and both the positive and the negative remainders are that.

You might see other compilers solve this with slightly different code, but the general idea is similar.

Comment: I see, is there a mathematical explanation for why `(x-1 & 7) - 7` would work for 2's compliment numbers?

Comment: @VineetPatel Yes, this expression is required to produce a remainder in the range from −7 to 0 instead of 0 to 7.  Try it on paper with some different inputs.